# Does ToHashSet() automatically remove duplicates without raising an error?

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset) I found did not clearly answer my question because it did not clearly indicate what `ToHashSet()` would do with duplicates.

Are they included?, removed? or does it trigger an error?

In my searches and testing, it appears that duplicates are silently stripped. The other questions on StackOverflow assume that duplicates should be stripped.

This appears to be true for all objects as long as the `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` are correctly overridden.

Am I correct or did I miss something?   **Assumptions create bugs.**

A simple answer of **Yes** with a link to documentation is all I need.

Two triggers for this question are:

1. The [documentation for ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) specifically indicates that it will raise an error on duplicates.  The documentation for `.ToHashSet()` says **nothing** about duplicates.
2. Seeing code that does a `.Distinct()` or `.GroupBy()` before calling `.ToHashSet()`.  That implies that the developer either did not understand `.ToHashSet()` or that they were afraid of creating a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A set cannot contain duplicate elements, by definition.

.NET methods document which exception they can raise. `ToHashSet()` does not list any exception, so we can safely assume that it does not throw any.

There really are two possible implementations for `ToHashSet()`:

1. It delegates the work to [this `HashSet` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))). The documentation's "Remarks" section states:

> If `collection` contains duplicates, the set will contain one of each unique element. No exception will be thrown. Therefore, the size of the resulting set is not identical to the size of collection.

Therefore, identical elements are simply skipped. This is the implementation that is indeed used if you read the source.

2. It enumerates the source sequence and repeatedly calls `Add` on an initially empty set. `Add` does not throw, since it states to return:

> `true` if the element is added to the `HashSet<T>` object; false if the element is already present.

In any case, no exception will ever be thrown. Duplicates are ignored, and the resulting set contains only the unique elements.

Comment: One can test this in C# interactive: `new[] { 1, 1, 2 }.ToHashSet()` results in `HashSet<int>(Count = 2) { 1, 2 }`

Comment: _".NET methods document which exception they can raise."_ This is rarely exhaustive, though: For example, the documents never state that `StackOverflowException` or `ThreadAbortException` could be raised, even though every method potentially could. The docs often miss exceptions from deeper calls, and `DivideByZeroException` too. Since the docs can be incomplete, and do not _explicitly preclude_ `ToHashSet()` from invoking `Add()` and then `throw`ing if `Add()` returns `false` — a valid possible third implementation — the Question is right to have asked what the expected behavior should be.